# Dell Lattitude 5511 fan always work when external display connected

Tags: drivers, nvidia, dell, fan, temperature

System - Ubuntu 22.04,
Laptop - Dell Lattitude 5511

When I connect the external display to a Type C port or HDMI, the laptop's fan starts and always works.
CPU and GPU temperature is 52 degrees.

I installed Nvidia drivers but this didn't help.

How can I configure the system not to use graphic card for external display?
Or not to start the fan at this temperature?

Comment: Sorry but I find your question confusing. If you do not use the graphics card how can the monitor work? You only mention the one device that gives graphic features. At 50 c the fan should be on. The use of the external display makes the graphics card work harder, working harder makes more heat.

Comment: @David thank you for your reply!
Sorry for the confusing question.

I think you are right. For me it looks like issue because when I use monitor in windows fan doesn't work :)